# Java Regex: Two different strings, not splitting correctly on first

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have two example strings:

```
"Seat 7: Bug One [ME] (82 power)"
```

and

```
"Bug One [ME] : xx xxxxx xxxxxx"
```

I need to be able to split on `Bug One [ME]` from both strings so I can replace it with different text. The regex expression I'm currently using is:

```
":? ?[^\\[ME\\]]*\\[ME\\] ?:? ?"
```

But when I try this, I get the following incorrect strings:

```
"" <-- empty string (which is wrong)
```

And

```
"(82 power)" <-- which is right
```

I want to have `"Seat 7: "` instead of an empty string.

I'm fairly new to Java regex, can anyone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT: Everyone has been suggesting that I just try splitting on 'Bug One [ME]', but unfortunately 'Bug One' can change. For example, I could be 'Fox Seven [ME]' and I'd need to be able to split on this string all the same.

Comment: Just use `string.split` for the entire substring. I think Java string library can handle that.

Comment: The regex for something like that would be `\\w+ \\w+ \\[ME\\]` Not entirely sure about how many backslashes, but you can test it yourself

Comment: Edited my post. Unfortunately, using split for this fixed string won't cut it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to replace `<some text> [ME]` globally, you want a regex like this:

```
(?<=: )[^\[]+\[ME\]|^[^\[]+\[ME\](?= :)
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=: )` Lookbehind: find `": "` immediately before the regex
- `[^\[]+` Find one or more non-`[` characters
- `\[ME\]` matches `[ME]` literally
- `|` RegEx OR
- `^` Matches the beginning of a string
- `[^\[]+` Find one or more non-`[` characters
- `\[ME\]` matches `[ME]` literally
- `(?= :)` Lookahead: find `" :"` immediately after the regex

[RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fI1fJ8/2)

Comment: I have no idea how the flip you came up with this so quickly but thanks! Shall take a look at the link. Udabest!

Comment: Oh actually you know what, I'm getting an 'Unclosed character' patternsyntaxexception on the final close parenthesis. Thoughts?

Comment: @user3905007 Okay, I found the problem. I forgot to escape the `[` inside the character classes, so both occurrences of `[^[]` need to become `[^\[]`. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use something like below if you want "Seat 7: " and "(82power)" and you are sure that there will be only 2 words between ':' and [ME]:

```
String s = "Seat 7: Bug One [ME] (82 power)";
    String[] sArr=  s.split(" (\\w+) (\\w+) \\[ME\\]");
```

Comment: Edited my post. Unfortunately, using split for this fixed string won't cut it :/

Comment: will ':' be there all time?

Answer (score 0):

Like the previous answers, I think you are over-complicating it a bit :)

```
(.*)(Bug One \[ME\] )(.*)
```

Comment: I think Java needs a double backslash to operate properly

Comment: What is the regex library or function that you use?

Comment: Not me personally, just from what I've seen on SO

Comment: Edited my post. Unfortunately, using split for this fixed string won't cut it :/

Comment: Yep, I read you edit and I kinda don't follow you question... Maybe if you provide a piece of code it would make easier to understand what you are trying to achieve.